# Performance between Powershell code and C# DLL

Tags: c#, powershell

Is there an improvement in terms of time performance if the code is written in C# and then the compiled DLL is used instead of writing the code directly in powershell?

Comment: Why not measure it and find out for yourself.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to do in the code, there's no right or wrong answer. You'll need to measure the performance and choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that it largely doesn't matter.  If you have poor performance using *just* PowerShell, it is likely that you can do things to improve the performance with still *just* PowerShell.

Another fantastic benefit of PowerShell is that the code is right there and easily accessible to many non-developers as they don't have to compile to iterate over it.  Any performance degradation as a result is worthwhile with respect to that.  However, it is pretty minimal.

Since PowerShell 3.x, it is JIT compiled.  Further, there are things done on the back-end to optimize what code actually does, in some cases.  In PowerShell 6.x, it was just announced that there is an optimization that even improves piping to `Out-Null` to make it perform like assigning to `$Null`, by making it do the same thing.

Further, there are now methods available on many objects, like `$Object.Where()` that will behave signification faster than piping it, `$Object | Where-Object`.

For these things, just be aware of the versions that are required for the operations that you're performing.

As some have said, however, when in doubt, `Measure-Command`.